# How to fit an ARMA model along with "usual" predictors?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima

Is there an R package that I can use to fit a model being a blend of the ARMA model and the ordinary linear regression? I mean something like this:
$$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_1+\beta_2 X_2+\beta_3Y_{t-1}+\beta_4 Y_{t-2}+\beta_5 \varepsilon_t+\beta_6 \varepsilon_{t-1}  $$
How can we fit such a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as an *ARMAX* model. Note that this is different from what `forecast::auto.arima()` with external regressors provided in the `xreg` parameter fits, which is a *regression with ARIMA errors*. If you search for "ARMAX R", you need to be careful about the distinction between the two kinds of models, because this is *very* frequently confused. More information on the difference can be found in [Rob Hyndman's blog post on "The ARIMAX model muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

He says at the very bottom that `TSA::arimax()` fits a general transfer function model, which includes ARMAX models. [This may be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25224155/452096) Unfortunately, [the TSA package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSA/index.html) has been removed from CRAN. You could try your luck with an archived version.